# Filter an array from an array

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to build a GUI that will eventually allow our second line team to easily apply look up AD accounts. I have got so far but I cannot get PowerShell to look up the value entered into a text box to then evaluate if the user exists in AD.

Here is the script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() 

$Form               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize    = '400,400'
$Form.Text          = "Add DXE Mailbox Permissions"
$Form.TopMost       = $false

$Label1             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.Text        = "Username"
$Label1.AutoSize    = $true
$Label1.Width       = 25
$Label1.Height      = 10
$Label1.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15, 145)
$Label1.Font        = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TextBox1           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox1.Multiline = $false
$TextBox1.Width     = 168
$TextBox1.Height    = 20
$TextBox1.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15, 165)
$TextBox1.Font      = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button1            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Text       = "Check Username"
$Button1.Width      = 120
$Button1.Height     = 30
$Button1.Location   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(199, 162)
$Button1.Font       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Button1.Add_Click($Button1_Click)

$Form.Controls.AddRange(@($Label1, $TextBox1, $Button1))

$Button1_Click = {
    $username = $Label1.Text
    $Checkuser = Get-ADUser -Identity $username
    if ($Checkuser -eq $null) {
        $Button1.Text = "Can't Find User"
        $button1.ForeColor = "Red"
    } elseif ($Checkuser -ne $null) {
        $Button1.Text = "Found User"
    }
}

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

I believe the problem I am having is to do with the line `$username = $Label1.Text`. I am not sure if `$Label1.Text` should be assigned to a varible, and if so how would I make PowerShell retrive the text that has been entered?
I had a quick look around and I am hoping that there is a way to do this without opening and closing another window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to a wrong object here:

```
$username = $Label1.text
```

That's, em, the label. Of course you should get the value from the `TextBox`:

```
$username = $TextBox1.text
```

Comment: ah, I see my mistake now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `$Button1_Click` action *after* you've defined it - otherwise you're just assigning `$null` to the `Click` event:

```
<# define controls here ... #>
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$TextBox1,$Button1))

$Button1_Click = {
  $username = $Label1.text
  $Checkuser = Get-ADUser -Identity $username
  If($Checkuser -eq $null){
    $Button1.Text = "Can't Find User"
    $button1.ForeColor = "Red"
  }
  Elseif($Checkuser -ne $null){
    $Button1.Text = "Found User"
  }
}

$Button1.Add_click($Button1_Click)

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

If you want to grab the username from the text box, change `$username = $Label1.text` to `$username = $TextBox1.Text`